# Entity framework 6 code first - one way many to many via annotations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it possible to create one-way many-to-many association in entity framework 6 with code first and annotations? Example:

```
class Currency
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}

class Country
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    // How i can annotate this property to say EF that it is many-to-many
    // and it should create mapping table?
    // I don't need navigation property to Country in Currency class!
    public virtual IList<Currency> currencies { get; set; }
}
```

On Java + JPA annotations i can implement what i need  this way:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "MAPPING_TABLE", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "THIS_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "OTHER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
})
```

so, does EF have equal features?

Answer (score 30):

You can do this by specifying the relationship explicitly using the Fluent API. Override the `OnModelCreating()` method of your `DbContext` class, and in your override specify the details of the mapping table like this:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Currencies)
            .WithMany()                 // Note the empty WithMany()
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapLeftKey("CountryId");
                x.MapRightKey("CurrencyId");
                x.ToTable("CountryCurrencyMapping");
            });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Note that - in my quick test anyway - you will have to `Include()` the Currencies property when loading the EF object to have the list populated:

```
            var us = db.Countries
                        .Where(x => x.Name == "United States")
                        .Include(x=>x.Currencies)
                        .First();
```

EDIT

If you really want to do everything with Data Annotations, and not use Fluent at all, then you can model the join table explicitly as pointed out [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7053393/925478). There are various usability disadvantages of this approach, though, so it seems the Fluent method is the best approach.

```
class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CountryCurrency> CountryCurrencies { get; set; }
}

class Currency
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class CountryCurrency
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public virtual int CountryId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public virtual int CurrencyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you... Is it possible to do this configuration only with annotations?

Comment: I think the best you could do would be to model the join table explicitly. So, make a CountryCurrency class alongside your other EF objects, and replace the `currencies` property in the Country object with an `ICollection<CountryCurrency>`. This has usability disadvantages, though, because EF won't be automatically doing the JOINS behind the scenes for you.

Comment: Strange that there is no way to do this with attributes. EF is a mess.

Comment: And what about cascade deleting from CountryCurrencyMapping? Does EF automatically clean up unused navigation records?

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna learn how to separate relations from EF code first entities. I have started a topic in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940036/about-c-sharp-partial-class-accesibility) about this question. I wanna separate the relation objects from entity, and I used partial classes. In my question I wanna learn how to separate partial classes by class bilrary. But couldn't.

While I was using NHibernate I was using XML mapping and creating relations here, In java platform is same thing. But I think Entity Framework is not ready yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in code first quite easily in EF 6.

```
    public class Country
{
   public int ID {get;set;}

   public virtual ICollection<Currency> Currencys {get;set;}//don't worry about the name,     pluralisation etc


}

public class Currency
{

   public int ID {get;set;}

   public virtual ICollection<Country> Countrys {get;set;}//same as above - 

}
```

Compile it, run it and hey presto - magic join table in the background. Depends if the naming conventions bother you. I personally think if you are doing code first, you should do it all in the code. Some people prefer annotation, some prefer fluent API - use whichever you prefer.

Comment: The question was explicit about a one way navigation. Adding Countries to the Currency removes that restriction.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but from what I can tell 1 way navigation properties kind of go against code first principles. What is the disadvantage of putting both collections in? Does it become less performant?