# Entity Framework: foreign keys for many-to-many relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a problem regarding navigational properties of many-to-many relations.
As I read on MSDN, there is an option to define a `ForeignKey` property to a navigational property. Now I want to use this feauture for many-to-many relation but I can't get it to work.

I am using EF 6.1.3.

My classes:

```
public class Class1
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Class2s))]
    public ICollection<Guid> Class2Ids { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Class2Ids))]
    public ICollection<Class2> Class2s { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Class3))]
    public Guid Class3Id { get; set; }

    public Guid Class3 { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Class1s))]
    public ICollection<Guid> Class1Ids { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Class1Ids))]
    public ICollection<Class1> Class1s { get; set; }
}

public class Class3
{ 
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } 
}
```

The problem that the navigational property get loaded but the id collection stays empty.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (SomeContext context = new SomeContext())
    {
        var classes = context.Classe1Set
            .Include(c => c.Class2s)
            .Include(c => c.Class2s)
            .First();

        classes.Class3;     // filled with correct object
        classes.Class3Id;   // filled with correct guid

        classes.Class2s;    // is filled with 2 elements
        classes.Class2Ids;  // problem: is Empty List
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** Updated the classes to represent the problem better. The many-to-many connection is created correctly on the DB side. The problem is just the property **Class1Ids** not filling correctly whereas **Class3Id** does.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity framework 6 code first - one way many to many via annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954429/entity-framework-6-code-first-one-way-many-to-many-via-annotations)

Comment: Collection navigation properties must only contain entities, hence your `Ids` properties are incorrect and should be removed.

Comment: Although this has been accepted, you may like to refer https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/226#issuecomment-288206793, where EF6 team is saying a clear "No" by using Annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the ForeignKey attributes - the relationship will be inferred from types.
`Class1Ids` and `Class2Ids` do not point to another entity, are not navigation properties, and cannot be loaded automatically by EF.
To get what you want you should define the Ids properties like so
`public ICollection<Guid> ClassXIds { get { return ClassXs.Select(c => c.Id).ToList(); } }`. This doesn't load the data from DB, just pulls the Id's from the navigation property.

Comment: Ok so when EF is not able to load Class1Ids because its not navigation property, why does it work with Class3Id?

Comment: Because Class3Id is basic property (and a FK), the other Ids are collections and loading collections this way is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I assumed that would work on collections as well.

Answer (score 0):

Below Class1 class should have a collection navigation property for Class2, and Class2 should have a collection navigation property for Class1, which will create a Many-to-Many relationship between Class1 and Class2 as shown below:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1() 
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    public int Class1Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Class2> Class2s { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public Class1()
    {
        this.Class1s = new HashSet<Class1>();
    }

    public int Class2Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Class1> Class1s { get; set; }
}
```

You will get then on your database a table named `Class1Class2` with a field Class1_Class1Id as primary key and another Class2_Class2Id as primary key also

By default EF will look for foreign key property with the same name as principal entity primary key name. 
If foreign key property does not exists then EF will create FK column in Db table with  + "_" +  
e.g. EF will create Class1_Class1Id foreign key column into Class1 table if Class1 entity does not contain foreignkey property for Class1 where Class1 contains Class1Id